# How to supress embedded Blank Field line in Crystal report 2013

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to supress embedded blank field line if Country Name isnull
   First i take the

1. Empty Text object
2. drag Country name,Zone name,city,Location fields in empty text object at time
3. then go to formate object -> common -> check supress embedded blank field line
4. and type formula in supress

>

```
   if isnull({GetZoneChart;1.CountryName}) Then  
               true   
             else  
               false
```

But its not supress the embeded blank field line tell me if have any solution

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to suppress the entire `Section 3 (Details)` or just the `CountryName` field in that section?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Country Name is a string, you should be able to use this as your conditional suppress formula:

```
{GetZoneChart;1.CountryName} = ""
```

That should be all you need and it should suppress the field if the Country Name is blank.

Comment: i WANT TO SUPRESS EMBEDDED BLANK FIELD LINE IF COUNTRY IS NULL

Comment: Go into your report options (FIle -> Report Options) and check "Convert Database NULL values to Default" and "Convert Other NULL Values to Default" and see if that helps you.